# Identify a card game where you make card patterns to earn points

Tags: identify-this-game

Please help me to learn how the game is called. I've played it in the childhood and have no idea how it's called.

Here is what I remember about the rules:

1. Each player holds a hand of 5-6 cards or so.
2. There is the deck on the table. Also a few cards are face up on the table - some kind of the "market". Players take cards to their hands either from the deck or from the "market" when needed.

   3. When a player has a card pattern on their hands, like 4 Queens, or 6-7-8 of clubs (at least 3 cards are needed), they can put the cards on the table in front of them. They are left there till the end of the game and will give points to the player.
   4. Then another player can add cards to the enemy player patterns, like if he has 9 of clubs he can put it on the table and it will give him the points.
   5. The game ends when one of the players will rid of all cards in their hand. Then cards in the other player hands will bring them negative points.
   6. You can play it with 54 cards, and with 2 people.

Comment: So far it sounds like one of the many Rummy variations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the comments, it's some sort of Rummy. If you're looking to get back into playing the game, I'd recommend checking out the rules and variations over at [Pagat](https://www.pagat.com/rummy/rummy.html).

Comment: The most popular 2-players Rummy is called Gin-Rummy.

Comment: Yes, but I chose regular rummy over gin, since gin rummy is not in the set of rummy games that fit the description. In the OP's description, players meld to the table the middle of the game.